# Using a DocumentListener to Check if a JTextField is empty

Tags: java, jtextfield, documentlistener

I am trying to have the DocListener check to see if a JTextField is empty and if it is empty to hide a button, id the textfield is not empty the button will appear
here is the coed that I have for the DocListener. I already added the DocListener to the textfield tfName. When the Code runs the button is still visible??? Am I writing the Listener wrong or am I adding it to the textfield wrong??

```
MyDocumentListener d1 = new MyDocumentListener();
tfName.getDocument().addDocumentListener(d1);


private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener
{
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
        { //is used when the user types anything into the textfield
            if(tfName.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                btnSubmit.setEnabled(false);
            else
                btnSubmit.setEnabled(true);
        }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    { //is used when the user uses backspace in the textfield
        if(tfName.getText().trim().length() == 0)

            btnSubmit.setEnabled(false);
        else
            btnSubmit.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you be using

```
btnSumbit.setVisible(tfName.getText().trim().length() == 0 ? false : true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be fine. However, in most look-and-feel implementations, `setVisible(false)` will hide a button while `setEnabled(false)` will grey it out and make it unclickable.

Also, I would recommend adding a single method to do the check in your document listener and calling it from all three interface methods:

```
private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener
{
    @Override public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { checkIfEmpty(); }
    @Override public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { checkIfEmpty(); }
    @Override public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { checkIfEmpty(); }

    private void checkIfEmpty()
    { //is used when the user uses backspace in the textfield
        if(tfName.getText().trim().length() == 0)
            btnSubmit.setVisible(false);
        else
            btnSubmit.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This will be especially useful if you need to do a bunch of extra steps like repainiting and re-laying-out the parent of the button (if this is not done automatically when you remove it).

Answer (score 0):

For reusable code and a more generic solution that will allow you to map 1 (or more) textfields to a button you could use:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DataEntered implements DocumentListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public DataEntered(JButton button)
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
    {
        textFields.add( textField );
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

    public boolean isDataEntered()
    {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields)
        {
            if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void checkData()
    {
        button.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JButton submit = new JButton( "Submit" );
        submit.setEnabled( false );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        DataEntered de = new DataEntered( submit );
        de.addTextField( textField1 );
        de.addTextField( textField2 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```